# Can I have an access to the secondary replica hosts the mirrored databases

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server-2008-r2, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm running SQL Server 2008R2 Standard edition on and RDS instance with Multi-AZ deployment.So can I direct my read quires  to  secondary replica hosts the mirrored databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-AZ deployments in RDS expose a single endpoint for incoming connections and "replicas" behind this deployment are not accessible directly: it is sort of internal magic. Multi-AZ deployments are more about durability and availability rather than scaling.

However on DBMS other than SQL Server you are offered to use [Read replicas](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/).